# Failure to Install opencv 2.4.9 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiling, opencv

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.9 on ubuntu 14.04. I am getting an error while compiling files.
When I run:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```

I get

```
runtime library [libz.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /usr/local/lib
```

And if I try to continue by running

```
sudo make -j2
```

The progress does not go beyond 13% and the following error is printed

```
somepath/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp:280:10: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an ‘asm’
```

I tried to update gcc compiler as many threads advised but it didn't help anything.

I hope to find some help from here

Comment: Can you confirm which version you are trying to build and which version(s) of gcc you have tried? Your title says 2.4.9 but the build directory suggests 2.4.10. FWIW I am able to build 2.4.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 using GCC 4.8.2. I don't have a local libz so don't get the libz.so library warning but I think it's unlikely that the asm error is related to that.

Comment: I tried both 2.4.9 and 2.4.10 but none of them was cooperative. So are you suggesting me to uninstall libz.so? I have tried to turn off the shared libs with

-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF

during the cmake, but the error on 'asm' was still occuring

Comment: No, I'm suggesting the libz warning is irrelevant. I don't know why your build is failing and mine isn't: how did you get the source (git? zipfile?) - maybe add the relevant section of the system.cpp file to your post (e.g. `cat -n modules/core/src/system.cpp | sed '270,290!d'`) so I can compare with mine?

Comment: initially, I was installing 3.0.0.alpha from git. Now I just tried the beta version from opencv website and here are some of the errors I got:

1. During the cmake process: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kthouz/opencv-Install/master/cmake_ou

2. The make -j process failed with this output https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kthouz/opencv-Install/master/cmake_ou

3. And here is the system.cpp file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kthouz/opencv-Install/master/system.cpp

And thanks for your will to help

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to install opencv-2.4.10 with the help of these two posts:
1. http://answers.opencv.org/question/37115/opencv-249-make-error/
2. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Briefly here is what to do:
(1) Pre-requesites

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

(2) Git clone the latest copy

```
cd ~/<my_working _directory>
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
```

(3) create build files

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_IPP=OFF ..
```

(4) start installing

```
make -j4
sudo make install
```

(5) link opencv to python path

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

(6) Build documentation (*optional* )

```
make docs
make html_docs
```

(7) Enjoy

Comment: This worked for me..!!

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to install using [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV)(Ubuntu Community Wiki), I was able to complete everything, but in the logs it showed the exact same error. After some searching, I found that this is an issue in the `system.cpp` if you are using a GCC compiler version other than **GCC 4.8.2** (I'm using GCC 4.8.4), though officially it states that it should work with any version after GCC 4.8.

This can be rectified by replacing the `system.cpp` in the
`OpenCV_home_folder/modules/core/src` with [this modified version](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/ea50be0529c248961e1b66293f8a9e4b807294a6) given by the OpenCV Team which will be added in OpenCV 2.4.11.

I found it preferable to open the original `system.cpp` in `gedit` and replace the entire text with the one in this version and saving it.

The official issue page can found [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3983)...

Comment: an edit and an upvote!  **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/665684/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Thank you! And yes, I'll definitely do that. I use stackexchange a lot and this seemed a good enough chance to start. :)